# Can I merge two equally sized arrays into one array with sub-arrays of merged values?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
```

I would like to get an array that looks like:

```
combined = [["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"], ["a3", "b3"]]
```

I found the solution in a Hash with `Hash[a.zip b]` which returns:

```
{"a1"=>"b1", "a2"=>"b2", "a3"=>"b3"}
```

This may have to be solved with a lambda function, but I was wondering if there was some quick Ruby magic which made this an even-quicker one-liner.

Comment: Hmm.. no future thanks allowed at the end of a question? "Thanks in advance for any and all answers" -- removed :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have `Hash` involved. `Array#zip` is the method you need.

```
a = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
b = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]

a.zip(b) # => [["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"], ["a3", "b3"]]
```

Comment: I don't have hash involved... I simply stated that I had found the solution if I had asked for the returned value to be a hash. And yes, this works - thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,

```
combined = [a, b].transpose
```

Comment: Are there any performance benefits of this method over `zip()`? I may put both options through the ringer later, but for now thanks for the answer - upvoted!